# Link images to tags and choose which tags using checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hi there I have 2 tables one called tags with bunch of names and the other one imgs with 2 colomns one is tags that would match the tagnames from table tags and the other one img for images links ... so What Im trying to do is to pull all images with the corresponding tags from the other table tags ... yet I still have not figured how to set which tags... heres my attempts so far ... thanks!

```php
<?PHP
include('connect.php');


$options=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags");
echo "<form action='' metod='GET'>";
while($tags=mysql_fetch_array($options)) {
$tag=$tags['tagname'];
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$tag."'>".$tag."</input>";
$picts=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imgs WHERE tagname=$tag");
while($imgs=mysql_fetch_array($picts)) {
$img = $imgs['img'];

echo "<img src='arimg/".$img."' height='300' width='300'>";
}

}
echo "<form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql join to fetch them in one query:

```
$options=mysql_query("SELECT t.tagname tagname, i.img img FROM tags t join imgs i on i.tagname = t.tagname ORDER BY t.tagname ASC");
echo "<form action='' metod='GET'>";
$tags_displayed = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($options)) {
    $tag=$row['tagname'];
    $img = $row['img'];

    if(!isset($tags_displayed[$tag])){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$tag."'>".$tag."</input>";
        $tags_displayed[$tag]=1;//unique tag displayed only once
    }
    echo "<img src='arimg/".$img."' height='300' width='300'>";

}
echo "</form>";
```

And watch out - mysql_ functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO prepared statements instead.

Comment: Hey but how do I make it dysplay all those tags under one img ? lets say my first column in imgs is tagname1 with img1 and second column is tagname2 with img1 also ... So How do I make it dysplay 1 IMAGE but 2 tags you know what I mean?

Comment: I edited the answer - with each iteration gather the images in one array and check if it was already displayed so that it shows only once.

Comment: You asked How do I make it display 1 IMAGE but 2 tags , not the other way  -if it is tags that should be unique, change this `if(!isset()` condition to tags.

Comment: Anyway, your code was OK then (little overhead from many queries though), only you should use single quotes in second query: `WHERE tagname='$tag'` if tag is not integer. And your closing form tag wasn't closing.